# Apache ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED windows 10

Tags: apache

I have been trying to set up my apache server but keep getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when I want to access through chrome (localhost:8888).

things i have changed in httpd.conf:

> Listen 8888
>
> ServerName localhost
>
> LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll" AddHandler
>
> application/x-httpd-php .php
>
> PHPIniDir "C:/php"

I have also port forwarded port 8888 but still not able connect.

Please advise me on where do i start debugging as i do not have knowledge on where to start. apologies for the noobness.

Comment: I'd check: 1) Is Apache service running? 2) Are there messages in Apache log files?

Comment: ah. stupid me. the service is not running. thank you for your help!